# Want to get CakePHP 1.1 working on PHP 5.3

Tags: php, cakephp, php-5.3

I manage a CakePHP 1.1 CMS website, and our hosts just upgraded PHP to 5.3, causing a number of errors, such as:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: banner_image in /home2/intiwara/cake/app/views/layouts/public_site.thtml on line 49
Notice: Undefined variable: news_menu in /home2/intiwara/cake/app/views/articles/volunteer_animal_refuge.thtml on line 73
```

I can hide the errors by altering cake/cake/libs/configure.php line 133 to be:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
```

However the variables and models are still not found so the page does not render.

I realize I need to upgrade to CakePHP 2.1, and every post I find dwells on this. However I'm the only technical volunteer here, I have only a few hours tomorrow afternoon to get the site working, then I am offline for two weeks' work in rural Ethiopia, so I'm hoping there's a 'workaround' solution I can put in place in the meantime. (The hosts didn't tell us this was about to happen..)

I don't need the admin functionality, I don't mind hiding errors - I just need the site to render. Is there any way I can trick PHP 5.3 to 'see' these variables?

Thank you hugely
Chris

Comment: Upgrade CakePHP instead of suppressing the error

Comment: There's not much anyone can do without seeing the source. Those variables are not from CakePHP but from your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you followed the conventions you might have some luck and be able to upgrade to 1.3 withing a reasonable amount of time if you have a higher level of experience with CakePHP. From 1.1 to 2.1... this won't go that smooth.

Without knowing the whole code and all the issues it's hard to tell anything, it's not even really possible to say if it would be better to try to work around with fugly fixes or to do a proper upgrade to 1.3.

If this is really something mission critical contact me in private and I'll get you the contact to a company who can get it done.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone - I believe you are right. The undefined variables are all model names and I only need read-only access to database data, so I hoped there might be a quick and inelegant workaround to get the syntax working I didn't know about.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the SVN comments from my conversion from 1.1 to 1.2. I haven't bothered tidying them up, (except for the odd "ED:"), as I'm probably the last person to upgrade from CakePHP 1.1 and I should turn the light out when I leave.. These are the steps after I'd done the standard 'replaced cake directory' and 'config' updates detailed in the appendices on the CakePHP site: http://book.cakephp.org/view/3/The-Manual#!/1.2/en/view/411/Migrating-from-CakePHP-1-1-to-1-2.

It took me two solid days to upgrade a reasonably simple CMS with my rusty PHP, and the effort dissuaded me from using CakePHP again due to the awful documentation and the intricacies the use of a framework introduced. (Although I wasted half a day hours when my host thought one of my template files was a virus so blocked every IP address I could get on.)

The biggest timesaver would have been if I'd have spotted form->error as a replacement for html->tagErrorMsg. Instead I removed them all, put the errors in the models following the standard practice in 1.2, then re-added them all. form->input displays errors automatically, but it was easier for me to use form->select than form->input('type'=>'select'.. due to the complexity of converting the options and parameters from html->select to form->input using regular expressions.

1. Html helper migrated to Form helper
2. ->renderElement() needs to change to ->element()
3. ->del() needs to change to ->delete()
4. generateList() needs to be migrated to find('list', array())
5. VALID_EMAIL, VALID_NOT_EMPTY (and VALID_NUMBER) replaced with 
   array('rule' => array('email'))
   and
   array('rule' => array('minLength', 1))
   -- ED: these were later updated to include default error messages, although I think I needn't have if I'd known about form->error(
6. changed 
   form->input to form->text
   form->submit
   form->password
   Look at the code here https://github.com/zeroasterisk/CakePHP-cake_up-shell/blob/master/cake_up.php for some handy detailed info.
7. controller this->redirects are now relative in 1.2, so I put an initial "/" where I hadn't in the 1.1 version
8. form->input(Model/property => form->text(Model.property
   html->tagValue(Model/property => html->value(Model.property
   html->selectTag(Model/property => form->select(Model.property
   $form->textarea('Article.intro
   $form->labelTag('Article.body
9. error messages now specified in model rather than template files
   with exception of controller-generated errors such as duplicate username when adding a user - these are set in the same way as before, but displayed using simply echo $username_error - ED: this was also a mistake - later changed to form->error('model.field', $custom_error, options eg css class)
   html->labelTag=>form->label
   tagValue=>value
   selectTag=>select
   in helper-generated HTML, use full stop as model.field separator rather than forward-slash, eg, html->value(model.field) instead of html->tagValue(model/field)
10. Remove san->sql and cleanUpFields
    Remove default error messages tagErrorMsg - ED: this and much of my validation updating was a mistake - I should have replaced html->tagErrorMsg with form->error
    Remove accent from Espanol option in form->selects due to new bug in 1.2 that can't display accents in option
11. creating model.saveString to generate sql insert statement seems to be working (ED: I'd put a method in the core of CakePHP that generated an INSERT stmnt for a model, allowing me to do automatic email backups)
12. Alternative way of displaying errors using integrated form->input method - more elegant, displays errors and all types of HTML input control, but regular expression to replace specific calls with complex customization parameter arrays would have been too complex/unreliable.
13. In controller, replaced model->validates(model) with this->set(this->data) then model->validates()
14. Validation:
    Added form->error calls to every input. (ED: should have used regular expression search and replace html->tagErrorMsg with form->error..this would have saved a lot of conversion effort)
15. Custom controller generated error messages must invalidate a fieldname and in the template, the field in form->error must match that fieldname, even if it isn't a model fieldname, eg, password1 and password2.